# How works a server and different clients?

Tags: jakarta-ee, networking, web-applications, server, client

I'm trying to code a small app with this features:

- Users registration and login.
- User profiles (basic data and some stats, i.e. nickname, age).
- Chat (one to one, group chats).
- A real-time multiplayer game session (something simple, imagine tic-tac-toe).

I would like to code the server-side in Java because is the language I know the most but, I have many questions about the architecture to use for my development process. I want to have clients from Android, iOS and web browsers connected to my server, so basically what I'm looking for is for a basic guide/advice about how to tackle this situation due to is my first app working with server-client.

What I have in mind for this is create a server using Java EE but it isn't clear for me if I should use sockets or wich kind of connection and communication system.

Thanks for any help,

Cheers.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and requires long dissertations about architectural patterns, communication protocols. I suggest you to start from small questions. Knowledge (and answers) comes step by step. For example try first of all to ask you: which kind of client do I expect to serve? web browser is a kind of client. In Android and iOS which are the kinds of client? Second: which kind of communication protocol is suitable for this client?

Comment: I've worked just with web browser clients, creating web dynamic apps in Java EE. One of my biggest doubts is: Can I use web sockets to connect my server and my different clients (Android, iOS, web browsers) and authenticate and authorize those clients through this protocol?

Comment: This question is more defined, try to ask it (not in a comment). Maybe someone has the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'try giving you my advices, aware that they are not fully exhaustive.

**Server**

- use a **REST** approach because it's a modern and lightweight way to design a client-server interaction. Designing a rest api let you also be fully indipendent from the frontend or client implementations
- use a **token** based authentication **avoiding session** management in order to scale onto more instances with less problems
- be prepared to use **real time** frameworks for chat and push notifications

**Client**

- Use a javascript framework like AngularJS and a responsive css framework like Boostrap
- Consider to adopt an hybrid mobile app framework lke Ionic in order to abstract the frontend development from the specific platform artifact generation

Hope this could help you

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I'm going to try with sockets.